# Можно ли в Jira сделать проекты вложенными?

Tags: jira

Можно ли в Jira сделать проекты вложенными?

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Все вдруг резко усложниться тогда В выборках можно объединить данные с нескольких проектов если нужно отображать.

Вообще, для серьезного проектного управления с учетом загрузок ресурсов и прогнозирования будущего нужно использовать профессиональное программное обеспечение для управления проектами - типа Spider Project или Primavera. В них, насколько знаю, есть такая возможность